# How to use erlang public_key:decrypt_private?

Tags: erlang, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

I try to encrypt text with public RSA key and decrypt this text using a private RSA key. When I encrypt user public key it works.

encode public_key

```
encrypt_public_key(PlainText, PublicKey) ->
[ RSAEntry2 ] = public_key:pem_decode(PublicKey),
PubKey = public_key:pem_entry_decode( RSAEntry2 ),
public_key:encrypt_public(PlainText, PubKey).
```

But when I try to decrypt this text using a private key, it does not work, and I don't know why.

decode private key

```
decrypt_private_key(CryptText,PrivateKey) ->
[ RSAEntry2 ] = public_key:pem_decode(PrivateKey),
PrivKey = public_key:pem_entry_decode( RSAEntry2 ),
Result =  public_key:decrypt_private(CryptText, PrivKey, rsa_pkcs1_padding ),
Result.
```

How i encode and try to decode

```
PublicKey = ems_util:open_file(?SSL_PATH ++  "/" ++ binary_to_list(<<"public_key.pem">>)),

        CryptoText = ems_util:encrypt_public_key(ResponseData2,PublicKey),
        PrivateKey = ems_util:open_file(?SSL_PATH ++  "/" ++ binary_to_list(<<"private_key.pem">>)),
      %erro in this line
       TextPlain = ems_util:decrypt_private_key(TextCrypt,PrivateKey).
```

Error

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 17-Mar-2017::10:59:29 ===
Ranch listener ems_http_server1, connection process <0.2159.0>, stream 1 had its request process <0.2160.0> exit with reason function_clause and stacktrace [{public_key,decrypt_private,[<<55,66,78,123,456,2456>>,<<55,173,2367,140,71>>,asn1_NOVALUE}],[{file,"public_key.erl"},{line,313}]},{ems_util,decrypt_private_key,2,[{file,"src/util/ems_util.erl"},{line,614}]},{ems_auth_user,do_barer_authorization,1,[{file,"src/auth/ems_auth_user.erl"},{line,51}]},{ems_dispatcher,lookup_request,1,[{file,"src/distpatcher/ems_dispatcher.erl"},{line,70}]},{ems_http_handler,init,2,[{file,"src/http/ems_http_handler.erl"},{line,22}]},{cowboy_handler,execute,2,[{file,"src/cowboy_handler.erl"},{line,39}]},{cowboy_stream_h,execute,3,[{file,"src/cowboy_stream_h.erl"},{line,172}]},{cowboy_stream_h,proc_lib_hack,3,[{file,"src/cowboy_stream_h.erl"},{line,157}]}]
```

I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Try changing `public_key:decrypt_private(CryptText, PrivKey, rsa_pkcs1_padding)` to `public_key:decrypt_private(CryptText, PrivKey, [{rsa_pad, rsa_pkcs1_padding}])`.

Answer (score 0):

I describle the solution for my problem. The problem is the public and the private keys are generated wrongly. The right way to generate a pair key rsa using openssl is:

```
 openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
 openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

These commands generate a correct key pair and the code now ir working correctly.